# IIS 301 Redirection (containing http or https) to another URL

Tags: iis, redirect

I stuck in redirection process using IIS. I want to redirect URL to another one. But the main point here is that the URL can be from Http or Https. For example:

```
URL A: http://www.example.com  - redirect to https://www.example.org
URL B: https://www.example.com - redirect to https://www.example.org
```

How can I achieve this scenario?

Thanks for help.

Comment: What have you actually tried so far?

Comment: Formatted example like code for readability.

Comment: Do you want to force redirection always to https?

Comment: What I have done is just redirecting old URL coming from **https** protocol to new domain. However, if the old url comes with **http** protocol then it wont redirect.

I want to redirect old URL to new one, whether it comes with http or https.